# Hibernate one-to-many unidirection association, select child from parent?

Tags: hibernate

I have a problem with Hibernate one-to-many unidirection association.

```
class Parent{
  int id;
  set <Child> children;
}

class Child{
  int id;
  int name;
  int birthday;
}
```

Parent.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="Parent" table="parent"/>
 <id name="id" column="id_parent"/>
 <set name="children" inverse="false" cascade="all">
   <key column="id_parent"/>
   <one-to-many class="Child"/>
 </set>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Child.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
     <class name="Child" table="parent"/>
     <id name="id" column="id_child"/>
     <property = "birthday"/>    
     <property="name"/>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

in the mapping file, I use one-to-many unidirection association by setting inverse="false".

How to select the right child with the his name, birthday and parent ID infos?

best regards
Thanks!

Comment: How is Parent.children mapped?

Comment: What would you like to do exactly? Find a child which has a given parent, a given name and a given birthday?

Comment: yes,exactly what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select child from Parent p inner join p.children child
where p.id = :parentId and child.name = :name and child.birthday = :birthday
```

Read on HQL in the excellent [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql).

Comment: Where is your definition of "c"? "p.children child"

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Typo. It's fixed now.